# $\epsilon-\delta$ graph

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this in Latex?

[image: $\epsilon-\delta$ limit]

I have seen the similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395153/how-to-reproduce-this-epsilon-delta-definition-diagram-with-tikz), but I'm wondering if there is a way to shade, have dotted lines, and have the dot? Ideally, I'd want to have a way to show how different $\epsilon$ values affect the $\delta$ values, i.e., as $\epsilon$ gets smaller, there is a $\delta$ that works.

So far, I've simply recreated the image in PowerPoint which I then copy paste in my tex document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: You could perhaps try adapting one of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160237/15036).

Comment: Or using the answer to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485690/15036 -- which looks very similar to yours...